# Scaled down ListView truncated

Tags: flutter, dart

When I scale down a horizontal ListView, the ListView is truncated. Here's what I see when it is scaled at 80%:

[image]

I am expecting the rest of the list elements to be displayed after the 8th element up to the end of the screen.

I can scroll the ListView, though, to display the rest of the list elements. Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const actualTotalItems = 40;
  static const sideLength = 50.0;
  static const scale = .8;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, scale, 1),
                height: sideLength,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: actualTotalItems,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        width: sideLength,
                        height: sideLength,
                        child: Text(index.toString()),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border:
                                Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red)))))));
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

Comment: I don't know what do you want exactly, but if you set the scale to 1.0  your list must be math on screen.

Comment: I've clarified my question. I want the rest of the list elements to be displayed when the ListView is scaled to 80%.

Comment: Do you want to scale down the list but still in math parent of view?

Comment: I want to scale down the list and have all the list elements displayed in the full width of the screen. In the above example, I should see elements 9, 10, and 11, but instead the list is truncated after element 8.